# How can I useParams() to filter over initial state in React, instead of making another get request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working on a SPA React project which tracks farms and their associated beds and could use some help. I'd like to render some data on a `FarmDetail` page by filtering over initial state with `useParams()` rather than making more fetch requests to `"farms/:id"`. I've made 1 fetch get request and saved initial state in an `allFarms` variable. I've rendered some `Link`s using `react-router-dom` which navigate to a path using the `id` of the clicked farm.

So far, the component renders twice, and on the second pass my `console.log(farm)` in `useEffect` does output the correct farm object. Trouble is, at that point it doesn't rerender as I'm not setting state and the component has already rendered so the return value is blank since `farm = {}`.

```jsx
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function FarmDetail({ allFarms, setAllFarms }) {
  console.log("render");

  let { id } = useParams();
  id = parseInt(id);

  let farm = {};

  useEffect(() => {
    if (allFarms) {
      farm = [...allFarms].find((f) => f.id === id);
    }
    console.log(farm);
  }, [allFarms]);

  console.log(farm);
  console.log(allFarms);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{farm.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FarmDetail;
```

I've tried to `useState` for the farm variable and `setState` in `useEffect` in order to trigger a rerender, but that doesn't seem to work as farms is then set to undefined and I never trigger the condition in `useEffect`. `allFarms` also just logs an empty array multiple times which I don't quite understand why. I end up with a `TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading "name")` which makes sense to me since `farm` remains undefined that way. I feel like I'm close, but I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for an effect hook here because there are no side-effects.

What you can do instead is [memo-ise](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) the `id` / `allFarms` combination

```js
const farm = useMemo(() => allFarms?.find((f) => f.id === id), [id, allFarms]);
```

This will re-calculate `farm` any time `id` or `allFarms` changes and re-render the component.

---

Even this may not be necessary if changes to `allFarms` causes the `FarmDetail` component to re-render. If so, you can even more simply use the following

```js
const farm = allFarms?.find((f) => f.id === id);
```

---

Given that this may return `undefined` if `allFarms` is not an array or the `id` not present, you should use some conditional rendering

```jsx
if (!farm) {
  return <p className="alert warning">Not found</p>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I saw your code.
And I am agree with Phil's answer.
You can use useMemo hook instead of useEffect.
And by the way, the reason, you component renders twice, is that
first your component renders (with initial allFarms data)
sencod your component renders (with fetched allFarms data)

And the reason, your component renders blank, is that you mentioned that

```
let farm = {};
```

inside your component.
So every re-render, farm will initialized as blank {}
but

> useEffect

only called when allFarm variable changed.

Hope this answer helps.